# is there a way to get around using 'await' here?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the documents in a subcollection by following the firebase documentation, however the error 'await is an reserved identifier' appears.

This is my code currently and I do not see where 'async' could be used with await and the documentation does not indicate that it would be used.

```
getAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    //reference to the subcollection of subjects in the user's document
    const subjectRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "subjects");

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(subjectRef);

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    });
  }
});
```

I have tried getting all the documents with `db.collection.('users').document(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('subjects').get()` where db = getFirestore(app), however this does not work as the error
'db.collection is not a function' appears and any soloutions I have found to it are not relevant as db is refering firestore not the real time database.

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can see the parent function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i editted my post to show the whole code block :)

Comment: You can use an async function in `onAuthStateChanged()` like this `.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {`

Comment: Is this Node.js or browser code? The error message sounds like your engine doesn't support `async` / `await`. Otherwise, I would expect an error message like `await can only be used in an async function`. You can use `.then` instead of `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the callback async:

```js
getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    //reference to the subcollection of subjects in the user's document
    const subjectRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "subjects");

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(subjectRef);

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    });
  }
});
```